# Setting default dialer no longer works on Android 4.4

Tags: android

I created a dialer app that works fine in 4.2 and 4.3, and would let the user set it as the default dialer after selecting "always" when prompted. After that, clicking on any phone number would automatically launch my dialer app. This would apply to the call log and contacts as well. After upgrading to 4.4, this stopped working. Every time I click on a phone number it asks me which app to open with. Even if I select the native dialer and click always, it still asks every time I click on a number. And in the application manager for the native dialer and my dialer, under launch by default, it says no defaults set and the clear defaults button is always greyed out regardless of what app I select as the default.  I tested this on a Galaxy Note 3 and a Sony Xperia Ultra. It seems that a few other dialers in the app market have the same issue as well.

My manifest is below. Am I missing something that is now required for 4.4? I cannot find anything related to this issue in the documentation or the source code.

```
<activity
    android:name="package.activity"
    android:label="Gravity Dial"
    android:icon="@drawable/xyz">

    <intent-filter android:icon="@drawable/logo_dialer" android:label="Gravity Dial">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>

    <intent-filter android:icon="@drawable/logo_dialer_64" android:label="Gravity Dial"> 
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="tel" />
    </intent-filter>

<intent-filter android:icon="@drawable/logo_dialer_64" android:label="Gravity Dial">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_BUTTON" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>

<intent-filter android:icon="@drawable/logo_dialer_64" android:label="Gravity Dial">
        <action android:name="com.android.phone.action.TOUCH_DIALER" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>

<intent-filter android:icon="@drawable/logo_dialer_64" android:label="Gravity Dial">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: I have the very same problem when I press on an button to launch dialer intent. It works on my note 1 with Android 4.2, but not with note 3 4.4

Comment: Did you ever get a resolution for this? I am trying to register my app so it can make outbound calls, but running into the same issue. Many thanks!

Comment: I did find one solution for Google Play Edition phones (Sony Xperia) but it won't work on anything else I've tried unless the phone is rooted. In settings->apps->all find the phone app and disable it. Any 3rd party dialer will now be the default without being asked. I'm still working on a solution to solve this for other phones. I haven't found anything online and I'm about to run out of ideas via trial and error. Combing through source code to see if there's anything I'm missing and will post anything I find here.